# chrome extension trigger alarm on boot

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have an alarm that triggers at midnight every day. It seems to me that if the user has quit chrome, the alarm will not trigger. Is there a way to trigger the alarm as soon as chrome is boot up (if the alarm didn't fire at midnight)? So to be clear, I only want to trigger on bootup if the alarm didn't fire at midnight. Here is what I have:

```
  chrome.alarms.create("alarm_test", {delayInMinutes: startMins, periodInMinutes: 1440} );
  chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function(alarm) {
  //do stuff
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

The logic is pretty obvious here: you should record (in, say, `chrome.storage.local`) the timestamp of last successful alarm execution.

Then, on extension initialization, see if the timestamp is over 1 day old. In that case, an alarm was missed and you should execute whatever it was supposed to run.

Comment: How do you know when the extension was initialized? Is there an event handler for that?

Comment: When extension is initialized, its background JavaScript is run, so whatever sits on the top level gets executed. See #1 [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages#best-practices).

Comment: What if the machine is in sleep mode when the alarm should be triggered? The extension will not be initialized again upon unsleep, but you miss the alarm.

Comment: @cabbagebot I'd expect Chrome to fire the event in this case. The API does not guarantee a precise interval, but some time after the requested time passed. It would be easy to test this is the case.